# How can I run commands in my system using a website running on my local server?

Tags: apache, web-development, webserver

I set up an Apache server on my system. I want to run commands and files using the website running on my local system. How do I trigger a file running using browser?

What i want to do:
I have a file `test.py` on my computer. I want to run this file triggered by a button on my website.

Answer (score 2):

I fear from the phrasing of your question that you might be unaware of the very substantial security implications. Don't do this lightly on an Internet facing server.

There are a few ways of doing this. The "Apache level" way is to set up "cgi" functionality in Apache. One way to do this us to add a stanza like below to your Apache config:

```
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The above will allow you to run files ending in .pl scripts which exist in `/var/www/cgi-bin`

A simpler way would be to do some kind of shell call from PHP if that is configured (a command like `shell_exec` or similar would do it.)

Comment: The question asks about Python (`test.py`) but you are suggesting making Perl (`.pl`) scripts executable.   Shouldn't that be `.py` in your `AddHandler` rule?

Comment: @StephenenOstermiller - yes  Good catch.